# SharePoint 2010-Calculation formula based on other columns plus a custom value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to create a formula that will insert a fixed percentage based off column values, for example if the 1st Qtr debt goal for Jan is 1000 I want a Fixed % to be conditionally added to the Qtr% based of "The Qtr and Month" Not sure of the syntax need to complete this formula, any suggestions?

example column values
Qtr (1st, 2nd,or 3rd) Goal (Debt, Income) Month ( Jan-Dec) Qtr% (1.5)

example formula
=IF([Qtr]=1st+[Goal]=Debt+[Month]=Oct[Qtr%]=1.5

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax will look something like this (you will need to tweak it to meet your exact requirement):

=IF(AND([Qtr]=1,[Goal]=Debt,MONTH(TODAY())=1),1.5,0)

This reads as:

IF Qtr is 1st AND Goal is same as Debt AND month is January THEN set this column to 1.5 ELSE set it to 0.

EDIT: You might have already worked this out, but if you have a month column in the list then your formula will look like this:

=IF(AND([Qtr]=1,[Goal]=Debt,[Month]='Oct' ),1.5,0)

Comment: Watch out; The TODAY() function will be evaluated on Item creation AND on Item update (of any other field)

Comment: True. OP should consider how this will affect the solution.

Comment: So use the date from either the Created column or a user defined Date